# multiple HorizontalListView using same adapter?

Tags: android, listview, adapter

I am using two HorizontalListView  with same adapter.But only one HorizontalListView  is visible ,i Can't figure out what I am doing wrong.

My Activity onCreate method:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.books_library);
            ScienceBooks = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.ScienceBooks);
        FictionBooks = (HorizontalListView) findViewById(R.id.FictionBooks);
        adapter = new BookAdapter(BooksLibrary.this, 1, images);
        adapter1 = new BookAdapter(BooksLibrary.this, 1, images);
        ScienceBooks.setAdapter(adapter);
        FictionBooks.setAdapter(adapter1);
    }
```

**books_library.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/ScienceBooks"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         />

    <com.devsmart.android.ui.HorizontalListView
        android:id="@+id/FictionBooks"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please add the contents of layout/books_libary.xml to your question?

Comment: @LeonLucardie I have added the contents of layout/books_libary.xml

Comment: Wild guess: you've added all your books to the one container wrapped by 'Bookadapter adapter', and the container wrapped by 'adapter1' is empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug if your set the `wrap_content` constant as the `HorizontalScrollView` height.
Until this bug is fixed, you can use a temporary solution by defining an absolute height for the `HorizontalScrollView` like this `android:layout_height="220dp` (any height will do of course). Using the `layout_weight` attribute instead  should work too.

Comment: when can we expect this bug to be fixed?

Comment: There hasn't been any word from the developer on that so far. I suggest keeping an eye on the github page: https://github.com/dinocore1/DevsmartLib-Android